# CSS Flex Box Positioning inside a modal dialog box body

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, modal-dialog

Could anybody tell me how can I achieve this style using flexbox? Pls note the modal close button in the right side of the photo.
[image]

This is what i have so far. I don't know how to place the close button on top of the image.
[image]

Below is my code for the bootstrap modal dialog box:

```
<Modal show={this.props.show} onHide={() => this.props.onHide()}
                >
                    <Modal.Body className ="modal-body">
                    
                    <div className = "data-container">
                    <div class="callout" data-closable>
                        <button class="close-button" onClick={() => this.props.onHide()}  aria-label="Dismiss alert" type="button" data-close>
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                        {this.props.data} 
                    </div>
                    </Modal.Body>
                    {/* <Modal.Footer className = "modal-footer">
                    {this.props.title}
                    </Modal.Footer> */}
                </Modal>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.modal-dialog {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 800px;
  height:auto;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content: center; 
  padding-top:150px;
  margin: auto;
} 

.modal-content {
  overflow: hidden;
  border:none;
  justify-content: center;
  margin:auto;
}

.modal-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color:rgb(221, 221, 221);
  padding: 2px;
}
.callout {
  display:flex;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  margin-left:47rem;
}
.close-button {
  border: none;
  background-color:rgb(221, 221, 221);
  color:red;
  margin:auto;
  /* font-weight: bold; */
  font-size:50px;
  /* width:30px;
  height:30px; */
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks ✌️

Comment: can you please provide working demo?

Comment: Use ```absolute``` positioning on your close button and position it to the ```top``` and ```right```.

Comment: @prettyInPink thanks for your answer. if I use position:absolute it just places it under the image, i need on top of the image. Preferably using only flexbox.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] like a codesandbox

Comment: @PriyankKachhela here is a part of my code [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/contact-8dqxr?file=/src/App.js) this is the best I could do for this issue. Unfortunately here it is not rendered in the same way as it is in my app. if you press on "Poze" button or Contact button you will see th close button in right side, as it should, but i want it on top of the picture. IDK how to describe it any better. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @TJ here is a part of my code [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/contact-8dqxr?file=/src/App.js) this is the best I could do for this issue. Unfortunately here it is not rendered in the same way as it is in my app. if you press on "Poze" button or Contact button you will see th close button in right side, as it should, but i want it on top of the picture. IDK how to describe it any better. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to specify your parent containers `position` as relative

```
.data-container {
  position: relative;
}
```

And then set position as absolute and right to 0 on container that containers your close button

```
.callout {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

Demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/contact-forked-63l7p)