# put close button at right corner of a panel

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the code I have so far:

```js
let burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
burger.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  burger.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
.settings-container .amd-app {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 575px;
  height: 280px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}



label {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin: 1em;
}
label > input {
  display: none;
}
label span {
  color: #6A759B;
}
label i {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 64px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: 0.25s 0.09s;
  position: relative;
  background: #deeff7;
}
label i:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transition: 0.15s;
}
label > input:checked + i {
  background: #1094fb;
}
label > input:checked + i + span {
  color: #29316b;
}
label > input:checked + i:after {
  transform: translateX(25px);
}




body {

  background: #708fd4;

}

.filter {
  position: absolute;
}

.burger {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  filter: url(#gooeyness);
  padding: 30px;
}

.rect {
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  transition: transform 500ms;
  width: 200px;
}

.rect:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 100ms;
}

.rect:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 100ms;
}

.burger.active .rect:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(-51px) translateY(50px);
}

.burger.active .rect:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.burger.active .rect:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(51px) translateY(-50px);
}




.close {
 
 
}
```

```html
<div class="settings-container">
  <div class="amd-app">
    

    
    <div class="amd-intro">
      
      
      
      
          <div class="close">

    <svg class="filter" version="1.1">
      <defs>
        <filter id="gooeyness">
          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
          <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 20 -10" result="gooeyness" />
          <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="gooeyness" operator="atop" />
        </filter>
      </defs>
    </svg>

    <div class="burger">
      <div class="rect"></div>
      <div class="rect"></div>
      <div class="rect"></div>
    </div>
</div>
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="amd-info text-center">
      
  
<label>
  <input class="cb cb1" type="checkbox" name="social"  checked/>
  <i></i> 
  <span>آموزش کارت حتی در صورت پاسخ صحیح</span> 
</label>
      
      <label>
  <input class="cb cb1" type="checkbox" name="social"  checked/>
  <i></i> 
  <span>ضبط صدا در صورت استفاده از تشخیص گفتار</span> 
</label>
      
            <label>
  <input class="cb cb1" type="checkbox" name="social"  checked/>
  <i></i> 
  <span>نمایش جلوه های ویژه ی صوتی و بصری</span> 
</label>
  
  
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue is I'm unable to **resize and position** the close button at the top-right corner of the white panel...

[image]

If I do this every thing gets distorted!!

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/MWvgxNM

Even when I try to **resize** the close button distortion occurs!!!

Comment: And also I need the exact button... yours seems different...

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely position the button with relative positioning of the panel.

To resize, you can use the [`scale()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale()) CSS function and the [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) property.

```js
let burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
burger.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  burger.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
.burger {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  filter: url(#gooeyness);
  padding: 30px;
  transform: scale(0.5); /* the number denotes the percentage to scale */
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}

.settings-container .amd-app {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 575px;
  height: 280px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.settings-container {
  position: relative;
}

label {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin: 1em;
}

label>input {
  display: none;
}

label span {
  color: #6A759B;
}

label i {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 64px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: 0.25s 0.09s;
  position: relative;
  background: #deeff7;
}

label i:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transition: 0.15s;
}

label>input:checked+i {
  background: #1094fb;
}

label>input:checked+i+span {
  color: #29316b;
}

label>input:checked+i:after {
  transform: translateX(25px);
}

body {
  align-items: center;
  background: #708fd4;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.filter {
  position: absolute;
}

.rect {
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  transition: transform 500ms;
  width: 200px;
}

.rect:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 100ms;
}

.rect:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 100ms;
}

.burger.active .rect:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(-51px) translateY(50px);
}

.burger.active .rect:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.burger.active .rect:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(51px) translateY(-50px);
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="settings-container">
  <div class="amd-app">
    <div class="amd-intro">

      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="amd-info text-center">


      <label>
  <input class="cb cb1" type="checkbox" name="social"  checked/>
  <i></i> 
  <span>آموزش کارت حتی در صورت پاسخ صحیح</span> 
</label>

      <label>
  <input class="cb cb1" type="checkbox" name="social"  checked/>
  <i></i> 
  <span>ضبط صدا در صورت استفاده از تشخیص گفتار</span> 
</label>

      <label>
  <input class="cb cb1" type="checkbox" name="social"  checked/>
  <i></i> 
  <span>نمایش جلوه های ویژه ی صوتی و بصری</span> 
</label>


    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="close">

    <svg class="filter" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="gooeyness">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 20 -10" result="gooeyness" />
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="gooeyness" operator="atop" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
    <div class="burger">
      <div class="rect"></div>
      <div class="rect"></div>
      <div class="rect"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you don't want to use `scale()`, you can always shrink the `width` and `height` properties. The only caveat with this is that you'll need to remove the parent's `filter` property, and substitute it with `border-radius` on the children:

```js
let burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
burger.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  burger.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
.burger {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 30px;
}

.settings-container .amd-app {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 575px;
  height: 280px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.settings-container {
  position: relative;
}

label {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin: 1em;
}

label>input {
  display: none;
}

label span {
  color: #6A759B;
}

label i {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 64px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: 0.25s 0.09s;
  position: relative;
  background: #deeff7;
}

label i:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transition: 0.15s;
}

label>input:checked+i {
  background: #1094fb;
}

label>input:checked+i+span {
  color: #29316b;
}

label>input:checked+i:after {
  transform: translateX(25px);
}

body {
  align-items: center;
  background: #708fd4;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.filter {
  position: absolute;
}

.rect {
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 18px;
  margin-top: 14px;
  transition: transform 500ms;
  width: 90px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.rect:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 100ms;
}

.rect:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 100ms;
}

.burger.active .rect:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(-51px) translateY(50px);
}

.burger.active .rect:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.burger.active .rect:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(51px) translateY(-50px);
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="settings-container">
  <div class="amd-app">
    <div class="amd-intro">

      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="amd-info text-center">


      <label>
  <input class="cb cb1" type="checkbox" name="social"  checked/>
  <i></i> 
  <span>آموزش کارت حتی در صورت پاسخ صحیح</span> 
</label>

      <label>
  <input class="cb cb1" type="checkbox" name="social"  checked/>
  <i></i> 
  <span>ضبط صدا در صورت استفاده از تشخیص گفتار</span> 
</label>

      <label>
  <input class="cb cb1" type="checkbox" name="social"  checked/>
  <i></i> 
  <span>نمایش جلوه های ویژه ی صوتی و بصری</span> 
</label>


    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="close">

    <svg class="filter" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="gooeyness">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 20 -10" result="gooeyness" />
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="gooeyness" operator="atop" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
    <div class="burger">
      <div class="rect"></div>
      <div class="rect"></div>
      <div class="rect"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wonder how can we resize it without zoom or scale!!??

Comment: @SaraRee I've updated my answer to show you how.

Comment: The second snippet not working...

Comment: @SaraRee the snippet is working for me. What does it look like for you?

Answer (score -1):

You can use relative positioning to the panel and absolute positioning to the close button. Here is a similar answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67354479/17109437

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll try to do better next time.